# React child components out of sync when using memoization

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-memo

I have a component that consists of several "bigger" subcomponents, one of them being a custom form `CustomForm`, which in turn consists of several custom input fields `CustomField`.

To improve the performance of the page I want to memoize that form so that it only rerenders, whenever at least one of the `data` values changes (`data` being a state of the main component).
At the same time, I also want to memoize the individual input fields, so they only rerender whenever their respective value changes.

Following is a minimal working example - I ommited the other parts of the app and simplified the form and input fields:

```
import React, { useState} from 'react';


function CustomFieldComponent(props) {
    const { labelText, data, handleChange } = props;

    console.log("renders", labelText);

    return (
        <input id={labelText} key={labelText} value={data[labelText]} onChange={handleChange}/>
      )
}

function compareTextfield(prevProps, nextProps) {
    return prevProps.data[prevProps.labelText] === nextProps.data[nextProps.labelText];
}

const CustomField = React.memo(CustomFieldComponent, compareTextfield);


function CustomFormComponent(props) {
    const { data, handleChange } = props;

    return (
        <div>
            <CustomField labelText="field1" data={data} handleChange={handleChange}/>
            <CustomField labelText="field2" data={data} handleChange={handleChange}/>
            <CustomField labelText="field3" data={data} handleChange={handleChange}/>
        </div>
    )
}

function compareForm(prevProps, nextProps) {
    return prevProps.data === nextProps.data;
}

const CustomForm = React.memo(CustomFormComponent, compareForm);


export default function Test(props) {
    const [data, setData] = useState({"field1": "value1", "field2": "value2", "field3": "value3"});


    const handleChange = (e) => {
        var local_data = {...data};
        local_data[e.target.id] = e.target.value;
        setData(local_data);
    }


    // other parts of the component

    return (
        <div>
            <CustomForm data={data} handleChange={handleChange}/>
            <br/>
            This is data:
            {
                Object.keys(data).map((key, index) => ( 
                    <div key={index}>{data[key]}</div> 
                ))
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

This code works as intended regarding unnecessary rerenders of the different components, **however** the individual input fields are out of sync. E.g., when I enter some text in `field1` and then in `field2`, the previous input of  `field1` gets reset (i.e., the previously changed value in `data` gets overwritten in subsequent inputs).

It seems that the problem lies in memoization of the `CustomFieldComponent` (usage of `CustomField`), because if I would use the non-memoized `CustomFieldComponent` itself within `CustomFormComponent`, everything works as intended and the user inputs are kept across the different fields correctly.

My question is, how can I achieve the desired memoization while keeping the individual input fields synced with `data`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a fix. The problem was the `handleChange` function in the main component.
It needs to be:

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    setData(prev => ({...prev, [e.target.id]: e.target.value}));
}
```